# Loading images into highest drawable folder

Tags: android

When reading questions on SO and "supporting multiple Android screens", it always says to place your images in 4 drawables. But wouldn't it work if you place the image in the highest resolution (say xxxhdpi) and let Android scales it down? . Scaling down will barely be visible ( at least from what I have seen) and saves the app a ton of redundant space

Thank you

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is in the paragraph above (I added the question mark). BAscially I am asking if it is valid way to only create one set of images and place them in high resolution folder

Comment: this will compress images in devices with low scale and it will have ugly shape, suppose we will work with your suggestion this will require a custom input, for ex : (splash screen) it's will require every draw in it for scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place all your images to only `xxxhdpi` drawable folder. It works but on the lower dpi devices, it may cause `memory/performance` issues. And also bad scaling image quality at some cases.

Assuming you have all images into `drawable-xxhdpi` folder; if you run your app on a lower dpi device, `scaling` is inevitable and it it costs much more memory usage.

Scaling is proceed at `runtime`. But if you resize them before runtime, there is no need to scale them again and again. It makes your app faster and smoother, use less memory.

If you want more performance and no memory issues, **resize your drawables and put other drawable folders**.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. But the app size unfortunately will grow quite a bit